# Remaining time on a bounty?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have had a $7000 bounty on my head for days (real-time) now.  I keep playing missions and joining friends games so the bounty keeps getting carried over to my next free-mode session.  I know many [different strategies](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Bounties_(GTA_Online)) on how to rid myself of the bounty, but is there any way to find out how much remaining time is left on my current bounty?

I really wish I could call Lester up and ask him...I imagine he has that info located somewhere on his hard drive.  All this constant running and stress is making my hair turn grey, and I am not talking about my character's hair!

---

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I am asking ***how do I find out the remaining time on my current bounty*** (whether it is located in the menu somewhere or on RockstarSocialClub); not how to lose a bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Bounties last 1 in game day, or 48 minutes real time. This 48 minute timer decreases as you spend time in free roam in an online session.

The best you can do is estimate or keep track of how many minutes you have spent in free mode since the bounty was placed.

If you are worried about running away all the time, note that time spent in your apartment will count toward this bounty timer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very easy to lose track of how many minutes when you break your free-mode sessions into multiple (actual) days.  Realistically, I play once a day for 1-2 hours.  During that time, I play deathmatches and races. I spend only a couple minutes in free-mode (only when I want to change up the game-type), so the idea of having to "log" my sessions sounds ***so*** tedious. However, if there are no other options, then this seems like the best method. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: I agree. I hope R* can add a better way.

Comment: I don't see it listed in the link you posted, but you can outlast bounties cheaply by starting a private, invite only session or a crew only session from single player. Press start, go to online, go to play GTA Online and select which session type you'd like. You can then roam and do as you please in relative safety. If you do missions, etc, eventually I find it will bounce you into a public session. I generally run missions starting from an invite only session if I'm not in the mood for open world mayhem.

Comment: @nosf I didn't post a link, perhaps you meant the link in the question?

Comment: Yeap, the IGN strategies was what I was referring to.